# What are -if they exist- the best books about UX and business?

Tags: selling-ux

I would like to know if anyone of you read - or if he heard about - a good book neatly explaining the importance of UX in business, something about the return on investment on UX making it clear that UX investment is worth the cost.

Comment: "don't make me think" - Steve Krug. Pretty much everyone in UX will at least have heard of it, and it's short. Which makes it a quick read for business types.

Comment: Krug's book is quite focused on Usability and User Testing, and while the application of his principles will generally lead to a better experience, this book will fall short if the goal is to "explain the importance of UX in business".

Comment: Go ask this on Quora!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good one to look at too would be the "Lean" series like "Lean UX" and "Lean UX for Startups."  They talk a lot about businesses getting things out the door fast by using the MVP model—minimum viable products.

[Lean UX: Applying Lean Principles to Improve User Experience](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449311652)

[UX for Lean Startups: Faster, Smarter User Experience Research and Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449334911)

The next one I have heard of but never read but it has to do with running UX in an Agile process:

[Agile Experience Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321804813)

All the books are highly rated on Amazon with good user feedback.  I could list out even more but those don't really connect with "business." :)

Comment: Great suggestions. I'd add that if the OP is still in the process of developing a strong personal sense of UX and UXD, that Jesse James Garretts "Elements of User Experience" is a must read. http://www.jjg.net/elements/

Answer (score 1):

There's a ton of books out there about UX in general. [Luke Wroblewski](http://www.lukew.com/ff/) has some great books that focus on common UX issues for businesses.

Also, Dan Pink's books are awesome for creative problem solving in the work-place.